# Не (совсем) принятые ответы

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Эта проблема часто случается с новыми пользователями которые задают вопросы, а после получения ответа пишут в комментариях "Спасибо" и всё. Не принимают правильные ответы, а про "голос за" я и не говорю.
Почему они так делают? Вопрос не имеет конкретного ответа․ Некоторые забывают, некоторым плевать, что другие на них потратили несколько часов, а очень малая часть и не знает что есть такая функция. И поскольку они заходят в сайт раз в 2 года то и достучаться до них нереально.

---

Что вы про это думаeте?

Comment: Смотрите на это, как на природное явление (дождь, ветер и т.п.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Чтобы проголосовать за [надо хотя бы 15 баллов репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) - вполне уважительная причина плюс не поставить.

Про галочку - могут и не знать, или не обратить внимание. На спасибо вполне можно ответить комментарием с просьбой принять ответ - часто помогает.

Comment: Насколько помню (не совсем уверен), до 15 реп. плюс от ТС запоминается и автоматом ставится  после достижения 15.

Comment: @0xdb Нет, это не так

Comment: тогда логично было бы при постинге своего первого вопроса на СО рассказывать людям о том, что ответы надо принимать. Или при появлении первого ответа на свой первый вопрос. Понятно что не принимают, потому что не знают. но можно как то встроить доп. логику для информаирования.

Answer (score 7):

Тут есть некая необъяснимая штука. Человек зашёл на ресурс с проблемой. Ему важно получить ответ как можно скорее, потому как стул уже подгорает. То есть дэдлайны и всё такое. Ну есть такое. Это нормально, как мне видится. Для решения проблем такие ресурсы и существуют. Человек получает ответ и дальше погружается в работу. Я не могу его за это винить. У него реально там пожар полыхает. Не до плюсиков и галочек.

Но есть еще одна штука. Вот у меня год назад возник вопрос, на который мне реально нужен был срочный ответ. Я не нашёл другого варианта, как задать его на ru.SO. И мне ответили! Вот буквально сразу. И я, получив ответ, подумал: "Так. Мне только что спаcли зад. Ну или почти спасли. Не важно. Главное, что я, годовалый фронтэндер, решил свою проблему, закрыл задачу, сохранил работу". А дальше была самая банальная цепочка умозаключений.

`Мне помогли. -> Профит. -> Я должен. -> Вижу вопрос, на который знаю ответ. -> Ответил. -> Получил +10 в карму и принятый ответ.`

И с этого момента чувствую себя частью этого комьюнити. Да, малюсенькая часть, ничтожная. Но всё же часть. И считаю своим долгом по возможности помогать людям. Я не семи пядей во лбу, но что-то подсказать могу. И мне кажется, пусть это и отдаёт нарциссизмом, что такие люди и делают подобные сообщества. Тут есть много ребят, которые делают тоже самое в 100 раз круче и больше! И дай им бог здоровья и благополучия. Я нахожу тут помощь, хочу ответить тем же. Да, репа - штука прикольная и хорошая, мотивирует, но посмотрите на параметр **влияние**. Вот я смотрю, что 6к людей увидели мои ответы или вопросы, которые, возможно, помогли им решить свою проблему, и прям радуюсь :) И вам того желаю. К черту циферки (хотя сам на них ...), но осознание того факта, что принимаешь участие в формировании комьюнити, очень радует и мотивирует!

Comment: Вот до тех пор, пока все здесь будут ... на циферки, стакоферфлоу и останется рассадником мусорных ответов.

Answer (score 2):

Я конечно понимаю что Поколение Х, психологический возраст на 30 лет меньше паспортного и всё такое. Но количество людей, принимающих "геймификацию" за чистую монету просто изумляет.

Открою всем маленькую тайну. *Конечная* цель этих "циферок" - не доставить интимное удовольствие "члену коммьюнити", который по-быстрому "нагуглил ответ и скопипастил его из документации", а **попытка автоматизировать нахождение лучших ответов**.

Попытка совершенно убогая и нерабочая, но уж какая есть. Больше циферок - лучше ответ. Лучше ответ - полезнее тем фрикам, которые сначала ищут ответ в гугле, а не сразу бегут задавать его на форум. Полезнее ответ - гуголь покажет его повыше в поиске.

И рассматривать пользу "циферок" следут именно с этой точки зрения. И тут же сразу все станет очень необычно

- скопипащенный из документации ответ стоит скорее заминусовать, поскольку он не несет никакой ценности
- непринятый ответ на проходной вопрос-дубликат пусть и остаётся непринятым. в идеале вопрос вообще желательно удалить
- полезный референсный,  экспертный, глубокий ответ следует следует отметить плюсом. А уж есть у него зеленая галочка или нет - вопрос тридцать десятый.

Comment: Бред какой-то. За какую чистую монету? "Попытка совершенно убогая и нерабочая" — не знаю, Stackoverflow пожалуй лучший сайт вопросов и ответов по программированию. На нем ищется тонны информации. И все работает отлично.

Comment: "скопипащенный из документации ответ стоит скорее заминусовать, поскольку он не несет никакой ценности" — если он отвечает на вопрос, то заплюсуют, а если не отвечает, то да заминусуют, но это и так понятно: при чем тут документация?"полезный референсный, экспертный, глубокий ответ следует следует отметить плюсом. А уж есть у него зеленая галочка или нет - вопрос тридцать десятый." — на самом деле надо голосовать за тот ответ, который считаешь хорошим. А галочка значит, что он помог автору ответа.

Comment: С возрастом поймёшь

Comment: Геймификация вполне рабочая. Тем более что балы можно вполне годно использовать - сделать вопрос с конкурсом и тогда на твой ответ практически наверняка ответят и ответят хорошо и развернуто.

Comment: @Andrew у вас в голове, прекрасные теории, которые, увы, разбиваются, о суровую практику.

Comment: Если юзеры воспринимают сайт как игровой или ведут себя не так, как задумано, значит они так понимают этот сайт. Это как протаптывание тропинок вопреки дорожкам из плитки. Тут есть неочевидные правила. Ну и, насколько я понял, поиск как в справочнике тут не единственная функция. Если кто-то ответил например на мой вопрос верной копипастой, это весьма кстати. Соотнести эту копипасту с прошлыми ответами и найти среди них самый трушный - это уже не главная задача и не простая, отвечающий не обязан быть экспертом каталога. Был бы мерж вопросов как в багтрекерах - было бы круто, но не просто.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема. Ну, впрочем, "обделенным" дают золотой знак "Непризнанный гений".

Мой алгоритм борьбы с этим (может быть и неправильный: я за него несколько раз получал едкие  комментарии):

- Напечатал ответ.
- Написал коммент: "Примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа".

Работает, к сожалению, далеко не всегда...

Comment: Знак _"Непризнанный гений"_ дают за нулевой рейтинг **принятых** ответов. Увы, те, кто обделён галочками, и этим знаком будут обделены.

Answer (score -24):

Дам свой ответ может быть слегка большой.
По сути тех кто не ставит галочку, я делю на два "вида".

1. Первый вид это **люди боящиеся конкуренции**. Они считают что даже те ответы которые ему помогли, опасно "плюсовать". Ибо это может повлиять на рынок  работавзятелей, не ставя плюс можно конкурировать с соседями.

   В чём то такой типаж прав и имеет под собой "сермяжную" истину. Ибо **капитализм**  так устроен что бы хорошо **продавать** и **покупать** нужен постоянный **дефицит**, и по сему **не всегда труд оплачивается и качественно оценивается**.
2. Второй  типаж это **бывшие вкладчики CCCР**. У них основная заведомо предвзятая культура по отношению к русской, хоть сами они и пользуются результатом этой культуры. Ибо если тебе будут на уроке истории рассказывать весь курс о том как "злая РСФСР с ела весь ваш навоз" то после определенной пропитки, вы в будете настроены пассивно агрессивно по отношению к участникам ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Как можно не ставить галочку человеку, который ответил на твой вопрой боясь конкуренции? При чем тут капитализм и СССР?

Comment: @SKIP ну да. А что не так ?? Я сказал не СССР а бывшие республики которые стали возвращаться к средневековью  им русская культура мешает ибо она заведомо конкурентно способнее чем средневековая .

Comment: Это проблема психологии 2000 голосов. 2000 заработать очень сложно, а когда ставишь плюс в голове крутится мысль что отдаешь свое заработанное. Это чувство проходит когда начинаются плюсики за прошлогодние ответы и тогда уже не жалко

Comment: Решительно неясно какое отношение плюсики имеют к принятию ответов и о какой конкуренции идет речь. Второй пункт неприкрытый национализм: когда человек презирает всех на основе национальности, то и ему кажется, что все его презирают на той же основе. На любом другом подсайте Stack Exchange одного этого пункта было бы достаточно чтобы прикрыть учетку автора. навсегда.

Comment: у этого человека много веселых постов,вот [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10258/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%85%d0%b8-%d0%9b%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f)

Comment: Брр... Работодатели ищут на ruSO персонал? :) Про СССР - это уже вообще какой-то супербред...