# Стоит ли удалять свой плохой (и заминусованный) ответ

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, удаление-ответов, оценка-ответа

Бывают такие ситуации, что ты берёшь и отвечаешь не по теме/не совсем корректно или поверхностно/точно не понял, чего от тебя хотели увидеть. Ответ, естественно и справедливо, минусуют. И тут ты попадаешь в ситуацию, что правками тут не поможешь, но и сам ответ не корректный. Нужно ли его оставлять? Возможно, кто-то другой захочет так же ответить и увидит мой заминусованный ответ и побоится это делать. Или данный вопрос только частично плохой и содержит некую полезную информацию, но если удалить плохую часть, смысл теряется и ответ превращается в бессвязный набор абзацев и/или предложений. Как быть?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Если правкой невозможно исправить ответ, чтобы он стал правильным (не обязательно лучшим) и отличался от других ответов, то да, его следует удалить. Репутация, потеряная за полученные минуса, будет востановлена.

Основная цель минусования неверного/низкокачественного ответа - принудить его автора к удалению. Участники, проголосовавшие против ответа, в тайне надеются, что их цель будет достигнута и **-1** им всё-таки вернётся.

---

За удаление заминусованого ответа можно получить бронзовый знак [Давление общества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure). <sub>Информацией о знаке любезно поделился [@nomnoms12](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10501/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82#comment44343_10507).</sub>

Comment: Кстати, за удаление могут дать знак [Давление общества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure). Могу предположить, что так сообщество поощряет удаление плохих сообщений.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Спасибо! Очень полезная инфа.

Comment: Лично я не знал, что репа возвращается как мне, так и "им". Спасибо за такое "открытие" для меня)

Answer (score 2):

Неправильные ответы не стоит оставлять потому что они могут ввести в заблуждение других, что приведёт к потере сил и времени.

Answer (score -27):

Я считаю, что не стоит:

Если кто-то другой даст верный и более правильный ответ, этот ответ будет вверху. Можете попытаться внести хоть какие-то правки.

Comment: Поможем Kend'у получить знак «Давление общества» :D

Comment: Тут тонкая разница между "неправильный" и "плохой". Если ответ просто хуже других ответов, его действительно можно оставить. Но если ответ вовсе не решает задачу, то оставлять его и собирать минусов никакого смысла нет.

Comment: "_Если кто-то другой даст верный и более правильный ответ, этот ответ будет вверху_" - Это не так. Вверху будет ответ, у которого больше голосов. Или принятый ответ, если такой есть. Верным и более правильным этот ответ может и не быть.

Comment: Эникейщик, за ответ голосуют в основном, если он работает.

Comment: @Эникейщик, можно настроить сортировку ответов, например по голосам  или по дате публикации, то есть нельзя предсказать какой из ответов будет _сверху_. Исключение только для принятого ответа, он всегда выше.

Comment: @andreymal Однако Kend - муж, упорный в своих намерениях... Кстати, интересно, какой рекордно минимальный рейтинг у ответа на ruSO? :) Ага, на мете - минус 22: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10255/195342

Comment: Я вижу тут многим их единички не вернули